# Recognizing a face in a set of images

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition

I am currently searching for a way to search in a set of images for a face which is present on an image I give as a starting point.

The basic idea behind it is that I have a folder of images e.g. from a party and would like to find all the images taken of myself. Thus after the party I use a webcam or something like it and take an image of my face. Then the library or program goes through the folder and compares each image with the "webcam image". Optinally the search could be fine tuned by not only providing one base image but multiple.

Is there a library available to recognize not only a face as in "a person is present on the image" but to detect a face as in this image has a face and compared to this other image the face has a 90% chance of being the same one?

Comment: You probably can get a PhD by working on that subject.

Comment: I have actually seen this in action at picture shop on a ship where they take a lot of images.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at OpenCV for C++ 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

I have worked with, and realised a application that could recognize playing-cards based on pre-loaded templates of those cards. But OpenCV is also excellent for recognizing (so templating) faces.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7UdYzCMKvw

Maby this is a good starting point?